# R select rows contained in a list (match) not working

Tags: r, select, match

I am trying to select rows from a data frame where based on a match between a certain column "ID" where the ID needs to be in a vector of pre-selected IDs.

I obtain a list of pre-selected IDs by running a "unique" command:

```
loan_ids <- unique(subtypes_frame["RefId"])
```

Then I want to select all the transaction for only these loans.

The following code should do it, but returns 0 rows (however it returns all the columns).

```
transactions_for_selected_loans <- trans_reduced_period[trans_reduced_period$LoanRefId %in% loan_ids,]
```

I also tried:

```
transactions_for_selected_loans <- subset(trans_reduced_period,LoanRefId %in% loan_ids)
```

Nothing seems to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here's a hint -
`a = mtcars[,"mpg"][1:5]`
`mtcars[mtcars$mpg %in% a,]` as compared to 
`a = mtcars["mpg"][1:5]`
`mtcars[mtcars$mpg %in% a,]`

Comment: Did you check that `loan _ids` has what you are looking for?  Presumably `subtypes_frame` is a `data.frame`, in which case you need to look again at your subsetting, as @Codoremifa suggests.

Comment: Thanks @Codoremifa and Cotton.Rockwood, I changed my "unique" command to `loan_ids <- unique(subtypes_frame[,"RefId"])` which produces the variable loan_ids as a "large integer" instead of a vector which solved the problem. Now if I can only learn how to "accept" your answer... I did a stackoverflow search for this too, to no avail...